# Javascript/jQuery to check if PHP output is json - how?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a script which outputs JSON when needed. PHP sets headers to JSON and JSON encodes an object..

On the JS side, `$.getJSON` received it and all is dandy.

The problem is when my PHP outputs plain text (which is a case I have to deal with).

The bigger problem is, as much as I'd like to work a code to check for type of output from PHP side, `getJSON` will not trigger the callback function unless it receives a JSON type output.

So if my PHP script outputs an error code, (not encoded into JSON routine) the JS wont react..

I needed JS to react in a certain way based on PHP's output type..

I tried to do the `.get` or `.post` JS functions but likewise, when my PHP output JSON, the callbacks for these don't get triggered/fired.

Comment: perhaps this would make some sense with code.

Comment: Instead of `$.getJSON()`, try using `$.ajax()` with no `datatype` option set. This will allow jQuery to determine the datatype on the fly but you still have the challenge of writing your success handler to branch appropriately to the data returned.

Comment: I think you should be aware of what data you are dealing with. Ajax is not black magic and jQuery ajax method provide multiple handler to manage received data depend on the request configuration (dataType). YOu can have only one PHP script that output plain text or JSON, but you have to decide on your Javascript what type of result you will receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at .done() and .fail() ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'blah.php',
    data: blah,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(){
    console.log('OK');
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(textStatus+"\n"+ errorThrown);
});
```

... also, here's some JS code to validate JSON ...

```
// validate JSON
function is_JSON(str) {
    try {
        var c = $.parseJSON(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks all. i get the point now. i guess .ajax is the only way to go to support both outputs dynamically..